# How to call method in applet from JarClassLoader and Applet Launcher which returns string data

Tags: java, javascript, applet, classloader

I'm trying to call a method in Applet1 which is my main applet from JarClassLoader used for calling this applet .And there is an AppletLauncher applet from where i'm launching Applets .My code is like this.

```
public class AppletLauncher extends JApplet {
private JarClassLoader jcl;
public void init() {
    System.setProperty("JarClassLoader.logger.level", "INFO");
    System.setProperty("JarClassLoader.logger.area", "JAR,NATIVE,RESOURCE");
    jcl = new JarClassLoader();
    try {
        jcl.initApplet("Applet1", this);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public String method3()
{

    String a = jcl.method2();
    return a;
}
}
```

My JarClassLoader will look something like this..

```
public class JarClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
public void initApplet(String sClass, final JApplet appletParent) throws Throwable {
    Class<?> clazz = loadClass(sClass);
    logInfo(LogArea.CONFIG, "initApplet() --> %s.init(); Loader: %s", sClass, clazz.getClassLoader());
    applet = (JApplet)clazz.newInstance();
    applet.setStub(new AppletStub() {
 applet.init();
    appletParent.setContentPane(applet.getContentPane());
......}
public String method2()
{
    How to call method method1 in Applet1.as class is already loaded as show in above code.     
}
```

I have tried using reflection but not worked...is it right r can we call in any other way .
I have referred from http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php..For JarClassLoader for packaging dll files.

And my main Applet looks something like this...

```
public class Applet1 extends JApplet 
{ 
 ......

public String method1()
{
    return abc;
} 
}
```

Please tell me how can i approach this ..to call the method.Finally i'm making a jar file and including that in xhtml page and calling that using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the three-argument for of `Class.forName` to specify which class loader you are using. (The single-argument form uses the class loader of the immediate calling class, which is a bit naughty.)

Note, loading remote code in Java is tricky to do securely.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Hawtin - tackline for ur reply.....I have edited the code .The class is already loaded .now how can i call the method in Applet1.

Comment: @user2135684 The best way would be to have it implement an `interface` or extend a subclass of `JApplet` that has been loaded by a common ancestor of both of your `JarClassLoader` and the class loader that loaded `JarClassLoader`. Cast it to that type, call the method as usual. If you really must, you can call `getMethod` on `clazz` and `invoke` on that.